# A good book with algorithmic puzzles with solutions (not of kind "how to pass and IT interview")

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

can you please advise me a book with algorithmic and mathematical (IT-oriented) puzzles. But I want not one more book of kind "How to pass an interview in Microsoft / Google / any other big company" but a book specifically on algorithmic puzzles with solutions, so I could resolve one and look for a ready solution to compare effectiveness both. More pure math than IT-business if you see what I mean.

Comment: Something like this - http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Fifty_Challenging_Problems_in_Probabilit.html?id=QiuqPejnweEC&redir_esc=y